ID this Scandinavian film about pigs and euthanasia please!
trying to identify a film I saw. I think it's Scandinavian (or maybe Dutch). About a young terminally ill man who steals money from his place of work, crashes his car on his way home and ends up unconscious in the field of some young woman's farm. She lives on her own and raises pigs. They fall in love and he spends the last of his days on her farm and finally to avoid him suffering too much, she euthanises him using the same gentle technique she uses with her pigs. Very touching film but can't for the life of me remember its name. Any help much appreciated.
